# Threaded renderer in QML

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qml

Threaded renderer is not working in the following code. I'm using Qt 5.4 on Arch linux-3.14 with proprietary drives.

---------- mytext.h -----------

```
#include <QObject>

class Thing : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int qm_no READ qm_no  NOTIFY qm_noChanged)

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void loop();
    int qm_no();
signals:
    void qm_noChanged();
private:
    int m_no;
};
```

---------- mytext.cpp ----------

```
#include "mytext.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int Thing::qm_no() {
    return m_no;
}
void Thing::loop() {
    while(true) {
        m_no += 1;
        emit qm_noChanged();
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

--------- main.cpp -----------

```
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include "mytext.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Thing myTh;
    QQuickView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("qmyTh",&myTh);
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

------- main.qml ----------

```
import QtQuick 2.0;

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 200
    height: 200
    property var name: "test"
    Text {
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: name
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            qmyTh.loop()
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target:qmyTh
        onQm_noChanged: {
            name = qmyTh.qm_no;
        } 
    }   
}
```

**Explanation:**:

There is a classes `Thing` , with its object `myTh`. The function of class `Thing` is to provide an invokable function which here is `loop`. This function will then continuously update the `m_no` value and emit signal. Now the question is that how can I update the `Text` (`name` property) while the infinite loop is running which keeps on updating the value to be displayed ?

Comment: What is the question? Explain the code?

Comment: Don't just dump a mountain of code on us, reduce it to the bare minimum required to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: What's up with this code? `Thing` has no `myLT` variable declared, signal from `MyLText` is accessed directly without `Connections` element...please start by reading [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) and in particular [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html). Everything should be clearer afterwards.

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation of the code. Please check the new qml code and explanation section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct for what concerns the QML part (now) and it works correctly. What is not correct is the C++ implementation. if you remove the `while` loop, leaving its content, and execute your code you'll see that the text is correctly updated.

The reason of such behaviour should be researched in the `Qt quick render` implementation. On certain platforms the render is not threaded by default. I guess you are working on Windows (see "Qt Quick" [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.5)). Hence, in a not threaded setting, by updating the variable and then sleeping, you are blocking the **whole** application, preventing the gui update.

You can use a [`QTimer`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qtimer.html) to schedule the method execution at intervals, or set up a QML [`Timer`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qml-qtqml-timer.html) for the exact same purpose.

Also, you don't need to save the new value in a temp variable (especially a `var` one which adds useless checks in this case). By setting an `id` inside the `Text` element you can directly set the text property. Here the revisited code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0;

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Text {
        id: myText               // the id!
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: "dummy"            // dummy text || left empty || use "qmyTh.qm_no" (ensure a correct value is returned at creation time)
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            qmyTh.loop()
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target:qmyTh
        onQm_noChanged: myText.text = qmyTh.qm_no    // text directly set!
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems like the used render is threaded, hence my reasoning does not apply. There should be other problems. You can try to track down the problem exploiting the debugger and by adding `console.info(...)` statements in the JS handlers. Searching for the problem could be useful to track (possible) bugs in the libraries.

Depending on the background processing you have to run, I still think that using timers wouldn't be that bad. It really, truly depends on what you want to achieve. However, if you want to try threads, Qt documentation is full of explanations (as usual).
Have a look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html), [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html)
and also absolutely [this](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). Mind that a "moved" object (see the links) cannot be registered as a context property so you have to use one of the other ways to work with threads in a QML project.

Comment: 1) I'm using Qt 5.4 on Arch linux with proprietary  AMD drivers "The threaded renderer is currently used by default on Linux with non-Mesa based drivers" [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html)


2) If I use Timer to schedule the method execution, what's the point of having signal ?

Comment: It works fine on my theaded rendered and blocks on Windows. Without the information you have added NOW I could only guess...so be polite with people helping you.
Given than, for 1) Try in any case the code without the `while`; it could be useful to understand what is the inerent problem. Also put some `console.info()` inside the handler to see how and when  it is called (or use the debugger...). As for 2) Jeez man, signals are useful but i thought you want to TRY the connection between C++ and QML (isn't this a testing example?) and using a timer is easy for such a purpose.

Comment: What the purpose of an everlasting loop like that if not simulating a back-end thread feeding QML UI? If that was the case, using a Timer was a quick approach to test the C++ <-> QML interaction. You see the point? You still can use signals, sure! In whatever way you want.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I was not rude, I was just asking questions. I'm not so good in expressing feeling in my text (I think that's why I never got good marks in writing). Actually the loop has to go in the back-end and I thought it can be done without using thread (actually never used thread before). And I'm really sorry for the text that made you thought I was rude.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information on back-end thread feeding QML UI or maybe some links.

Comment: Added some links. The problem you have should be really tracked down. Could be a stupid bug as well as a serious one which should be fixed to guarantee productivity on such a system.

Comment: As you have suggested to use `console.info` I tested the code in two ways. 1) I simply added `console.info` and found that the render is threaded; it's changing the `text` property every time the `qm_noChanged` signal is emitted but the screen is not updating the result until the loop has finished executing.So if you add the `m_no < 10` in the while condition you can see the last result. I don't know why the screen is not updated each time.

Comment: 2) I sub-classed `QThread` and reimplemented the `run()` function. The result were the same but this time the screen was updated every time the `text` property was updated.

Comment: On windows the behaviour was the first described. It seems to me the execution is not threaded as expected. Cannot say if it is a bug or not but could be worth to [report it](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa). Just use this same simple example in the description of the wrong behaviour